# How to read multiple pdf from a folder one by one

Tags: python, dataframe, pdf

I'm trying to extract data from a pdf file and convert it into pandas dataframe
I used 'fitz' from Pymupdf module to extract the data.
and then with pandas i'm converting it into dataframe

```
from pathlib import Path
# returns all file paths that has .pdf as extension in the specified directory
pdf_search = Path("path").glob("*.pdf")
# convert the glob generator out put to list
# skip this if you are comfortable with generators and pathlib
pdf_files = pdf_files = [str(file.absolute()) for file in pdf_search]
```

#Code for data extraction:

```
for pdf in pdf_files:
    with fitz.open(pdf) as doc:
        pypdf_text = ""
        for page in doc:
            pypdf_text += page.getText()
```

**The above code is only extracting the data for last pdf in the folder. and thus giving the result for only that pdf**

But similarly, I have a folder which contains many pdf documents. My goal is to read each pdf file one by one from the folder and do the text extraction and then convert it into dataframe.
How can I do that in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pathlib` builtin function to list out all the pdfs in your directory

```py
from pathlib import Path
# returns all file paths that has .pdf as extension in the specified directory
pdf_search = Path("<path>/<to>/<pdfs>/").glob("*.pdf")
# convert the glob generator out put to list
# skip this if you are comfortable with generators and pathlib
pdf_files = pdf_files = [str(file.absolute()) for file in pdf_search]
```

Now you can simply run your block of code in a loop to iterate over the pdfs.

for example:

```py
for pdf in pdf_files:
    with fitz.open(pdf) as doc:
        ...
```

Comment: I tried the code it's this error 'mupdf: cannot open 1.pdf: No such file or directory'

Comment: I have updated the code to return the absolute path instead of the filename. Try the updated one at line 6: `pdf_files = [str(file.absolute()) for file in pdf_search]
`

Comment: yes it worked, (now it's iterating through the folder )but it's extracting data only for the last pdf (and not for all the pdfs in the folder). I'm editing the complete code. it would be a big help if you check that once too

Comment: I've updated the complete code in question @Sabbir Ahmed

Comment: declare `pypdf_text = ""` this statement out of the `for` block. your code is initiating the `pypdf_text` to empty string each time the loop is running. so you are getting the last pdf string only. @AyeshaGondekar

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import PyPDF2
import re

for k in range(1,100):
    # open the pdf file
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("C:/my_path/file%s.pdf"%(k))

    # get number of pages
    NumPages = object.getNumPages()


    # extract text and do the search
    for i in range(0, NumPages):
        PageObj = object.getPage(i)
        print("this is page " + str(i)) 
        Text = PageObj.extractText() 
        # print(Text)
```

or this:

```
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
allyourfiles = os.listdir(fold)
firstpdf = ""
for i in allyourfiles:
    if '.pdf' in i:
        firstpdf = i
        break

with open('F:/technophile/Proj/SOURCE/'+firstpdf, 'rb') as fh:

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, caching=True, check_extractable=True):
        page_interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
    allyourpdf.append(text)
```

Comment: you need to import what i added @AyeshaGondekar

Comment: the first snippet work? @AyeshaGondekar

Answer (score 0):

Here you can achieve this using `pathlib` as per explain above.
Here is the full solution for your task.

**1.Function for text extraction.**

```
def pymupdf_extract(file_path):
  # OCR the PDF using the default 'text' parameter
  ocr_text=[]
  with fitz.open(file_path) as doc:
      for page in doc:
          text = page.get_text()
          ocr_text.append(text)
          # print(text)
  return ocr_text
```

**2. For reading multiple files from specified folder**

```
from pathlib import Path
# returns all file paths that has .pdf as extension in the specified directory
pdf_search = Path("/content/CVs").glob("*.pdf")
# convert the glob generator out put to list
# skip this if you are comfortable with generators and pathlib
pdf_files = pdf_files = [str(file.absolute()) for file in pdf_search]
```

**3. For extracting text from all files at once.**

```
cv_data=[]

for pdf_path in pdf_files:
  cv_mess_text=pymupdf_extract(pdf_path) 
  cv_data.append(cv_mess_text)
```

Above code take each file and store its extracted data as string in cv_data list